# Sending % through @RequestParam in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-request-parameters

How to send `%` using `@RequestParam` in Spring ?

I'm calling the API by this URL : `http://localhost:8080/springmvc/test?param1=%`

But I'm not able to get the % in the API. When I'm debugging, I'm getting `param1 = null` but I want to get the real character `%`. How to get that ?

This is my API :

```
public List<Test> testParam(
            @PathVariable("test") string test,
            @RequestParam(value = "param1", required = false) string myParaml) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send special characters in UTF-8 encoded standard in the URL.

Try to send `%` as `%25`, which is **UTF-8 encoded** equivalent.

```
http://localhost:8080/springmvc/test?param1=%25
```

This will work. Refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for more.

Answer (score 3):

Use URL encoding for special symbols as parameters

```
%   =  %25
```

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

You need to decode if want to read in Java
[Ref 2](https://www.baeldung.com/java-url-encoding-decoding)